# Set Up SSH Agent for git

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent

I don't want to enter my ssh password every time I do git push or git pull to/from a remote repository I access via ssh (login via user name and password).

```
ssh-agent
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Doesn't work. I still have to enter my password every time I want to push/pull.

What else do I need to do to make it work?

If I execute

```
ssh-agent bash
```

and then try to push twice in that same terminal, I still have to enter my password twice.

Comment: And you've ensured that the shell in which you are issuing the `git` commands has access to the `ssh-agent` ?  And you have loaded the appropriate key in the agent with `ssh-add` ?   Run `ssh-add -l` to list the fingerprints of all keys loaded in whichever agent is accessible via `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Comment: The `ssh-agent` only works with private/public keys. It does not hold your user login password.

Comment: Many git repositories use passwords for https access, or asymmetric keys but not passwords with ssh access.  `ssh-agent` will cache ssh keys but not passwords; the git credential-helper option will cache passwords but not (afaik) keys.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the job of an  ssh agent. I'm using username and password. Can I store my password only in ram? I don't want it to just lie around in my home folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Oh, I misunderstood the job of an ssh agent. I'm using username and password. Can I store my password only in ram? I don't want it to just lie around in my home folder. – UTF-8

No with `openssh` standard tools. SSH-agent is for keys, that are added before using (now they can be added also with their first usage, but it is different story).

If you want to he able to pass passwords, there is `sshpass`, which can read a passwords from environment variables, but note, that it is certainly not recommended from security point of view. If you care about security, set up a public key authentication.

Comment: But wouldn't it have the same effect got the stored passphrase along with the private key or the stored password stolen? (If someone can steal the stored passphrase / password, it's probably very easy for them to steal the private key as well.) So why no caching for passwords (only in ram)?

Comment: But the `ssh-agent` does not store the passphrase. It stores only encrypted key in the memory (protected from dumping). You can steal the password by remembering it, but not the private key (which is the SSH encouraging to use 25 years already).

Comment: So you still have to enter the passphrase every time?

Comment: No. Only once per session. The key is decrypted in memory (sorry, in the last comment I used a wrong word)

Comment: Okay, thanks! I accept this answer because it's the most helpful one and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to achieve what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-agent` needs to provide variables to your environment, so the right way to use it is:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

then, you can use `ssh-add` to add keys to your agent. Read `man ssh-agent;man ssh-add`.

For example (YMMV):

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1003/keyring-ozv0oa/ssh
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 26624
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AGENT_PID=26624
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-FUVLa89gGIpt/agent.26623
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
w3@aardvark:~(1)$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/w3/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/w3/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/w3/.ssh/id_rsa)
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ env | grep SSH
SSH_AGENT_PID=26624
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-FUVLa89gGIpt/agent.26623
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ssh-add -l
2048 a7:56:f0:86:ab:d3:ec:56:3c:84:05:9e:61:38:a9:7b /home/w3/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
w3@aardvark:~(0)$
```